# Quartz.Net Scheduler not working in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, quartz

So I have created a SimpleSchedular using Quartz.Net in C# as below -

I have created this inside `WebApi` project.

```
// Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
 NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
 {
     { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
 };
 StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
 IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

 // and start it off
 await scheduler.Start();

 // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
 IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<IDGJob>()
     .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
     .Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(5).RepeatForever())
    .Build();

 // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
 await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

**This worked like a charm in localhost BUT once I deployed it to Azure it did not do anything.**

So I did some googling and found that Azure works on Eastern Standard Time -

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var cronScheduleBuilder = CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(19, 10)
                                              .InTimeZone(timeZoneInfo);
```

and changed the Scheduler as -

```
 ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
     .StartNow()
     .WithSchedule(cronScheduleBuilder)
     .Build();
```

I also tried UTC format as well.

BUT still nothing is working.

I even used `RoleEntryPoint` class but result again the same.

Does this Quartz really works on Azure or am i missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but there's a high chance your web app is going offline. Make sure you're with always on enabled:

[image]

Comment: Ok, for how how long the site remains UP after someone hits the url ? In other words after how much time the site goes to SLEEP if kept idle

Comment: usually it's 20 minutes

Comment: so in that case if i schedule the job for every 5 minutes. Then if someone comes and hits it, the scheduler will sure be running in that case. Is it ?

Comment: Well in my case the AlwaysON option is OFF due to pricing. Hence iam trying to devise a way to run scheduler.

Comment: move to Azure Functions and use the native Time Trigger (and use Consumption Plan)

Comment: So in your opinion, if AlwaysOn is put to OFF there is no way to implement Quartz scheduling ?