# Quartz.net in API with .NET not working in azure after hosting but working in local

Tags: c#, .net, azure

```
 public static void Start()
        {
            ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler scheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            scheduler.Start();

  IJobDetail nJob = JobBuilder.Create<NService>().Build();

     
            ITrigger nTrigger = TriggerBuilder
                .Create()
                .WithCronSchedule("0 0 11 ? * MON-FRI *")
                .Build();

         
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(nJob, nTrigger);

}
```

The above function is in a service and the function need to be triggered everyday at 11 o'clock. Then in the Global.asax.cs the function is called

```
Scheduler.Start();
```

This works perfectly in local IIS but when hosted in azure the function is not triggered.

Comment: Check the event viewer on server to see if any errors occurred.  What account is used to start service?  Default account is a system account with no environmental variables.  Often when a service requires an environment setting it will fail when it is missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quartz.Net Scheduler not working in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62920206/quartz-net-scheduler-not-working-in-azure)

Comment: As a sidenote: please have a look at [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) since they are explicitly meant for things like this.

Comment: @DeepDave-MT no thats not working