Quartz.NET scheduler not working on Azure environment
I have created a SimpleSchedular using Quartz.Net in C# as below
IJobDetail testjob = JobBuilder.Create<TestJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("rrtestjob", "rrtestgroup1")
                    .Build();
     ITrigger testtrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                   .WithIdentity("rrtesttrigger1", "rrtestgroup1")
                     .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).WithRepeatCount(29))
                    .Build();
    await _quartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(testjob, testtrigger);
    if (!_quartzScheduler.IsStarted)
      await _quartzScheduler.Start();

It working fine locally. But when I deploy it on Azure server, it never worked.
Also pointing in this question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62920206/quartz-net-scheduler-not-working-in-azure", "Always On" option is On for my azure app.
How to fix it? Is there any other solution regarding it?

Run server timer in your application, do something that can be observable (write to database, log, etc.) Everything to ensure that your process is started and active.

I am actually using cron expressions, in that case server timer not work. I am looking to its alternate (HangFire scheduler)
